# How to search for exact match in shell script which excludes characters before and after the match?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

```
 awk '/[a-z]\+|\+[a-z]/{print NR, echo ":", $0, echo "[SHOULD BE IN FORMAT  [<space>operator<space>]"}' file.txt
```

I have some requirement like if there is no space before or after any operator should through error in shell. So I came up with something like this:

- if there is no space before `+` or no space after `+` will through the message.
- But if I am doing the same case for `-`  operator like

  ```
  awk '/[a-z]\-|\-[a-z]/{print NR, echo ":", $0, echo "[SHOULD BE IN FORMAT [<space>operator<space>]"}' file.text
  ```

  though it works for the following cases: `[ a-b, a -b, a- b ]` but fails in following case like
- if in the file.text there is some line like

  ```
  /*
      this->name = "string" 
  */
  //here it is showing the message like  echo "[SHOULD BE IN FORMAT [<space>operator<space>]"}' which is not desired because it is also searches for - in ->.
  ```

So please suggest to fix it?

Comment: Please take time to format properly your thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the string -> before the above matches and replace it with something that won't fail the test. (like the space character).

Answer (score 0):

Use `($0!~ /(.*\->.*)/)` to exclude lines containing `->`

```
awk ' \
   ($0~/([a-z]\-|\-[a-z])/) && ($0!~ /(.*\->.*)/)                                 \
   {print NR, echo ":", $0, echo "[SHOULD BE IN FORMAT [<space>operator<space>]"} \
' file.txt
```

But this will only work if you don't have things like `a->exp = r-j`: line would be excluded forever. Otherwise, credits to Mike, use `sub` to replace `->` by `..` before checking for your pattern; try this:

```
awk ' { \
   tmp_line = $0 ;                                                                \
   sub("->", "..", tmp_line) ;                                                    \
   if ( tmp_line ~/([a-z]\-|\-[a-z])/)                                            \
   {print NR, echo ":", $0, echo "[SHOULD BE IN FORMAT [<space>operator<space>]"} \
  } ' file.txt
```